# Format HTML in a php file

Tags: phpstorm, code-formatting

How do I format html code in a php file in JetBrains PhpStorm? When I use <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> it only formats the php code.

Code sample:

```
@extends('Layout.Main')

    @section('script2')
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $("#toc").tocify({ selectors: '' })
            })
        </script>
    @stop
    @section('content')
    <div class="page-title">
        <div class="title-env">
            <h1 class="title">{{ $book->title }}</h1>
            <p class="description">{{ $book->author }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="row">
        <h3> Original Chapters: <br></h3>

        @foreach($chapters as $c)
            {{ $c->title }} <a href="../customizechapter/{{ $c->id }}"> Customize </a> <br>
        @endforeach
    </div>
        @if(!empty($customchapters))
        <div id="row">
            <h3>Custom Chapters:<br></h3>
            @foreach($customchapters as $c)
              {{ $c->title }}  <a href="../editchapter/{{ $c->id }}"> Edit </a> <a href="../deletecustomchapter/{{ $c->id }} . / .{{ $book->id }}"> delete</a> <br>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        @endif

    @stop
```

Comment: **First of all** -- it's a blade template file and not pure php code. **Secondly:** PhpStorm version used?

Comment: Yes i know, my question how do i format that code. I am using version 8

Comment: 1) You will be surprised .. but formatting pure HTML file, formatting HTML in PHP file and formatting in blade file are **3 different things** 2) v8 comes in 4 different versions: 8.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2 & 8.0.3 -- which one is yours? Not all v8 versions support formatting of blade files.